# What's the rationale for not letting me accept my own answer for 2 days?

Tags: discussion, questions, accepted-answer

About one hour after [asking a question](https://serverfault.com/questions/498325/xenapp-web-interface-user-loging-from-two-different-browsers-or-machines-dis), I found the answer on my own. I therefore wrote an answer to my own question, documenting the process. However, when I wanted to accept my own answer, I was greeted with a error saying there is a two days cooldown period during which I can't accept my own answer.

Now, if that's the rule, I'm fine with it (except that I risk to forget it, but that's my problem) but I was wondering what was the rational behind this. Is it to prevent self-promotion spam or something like this ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a [Meta.StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) question about rate-limitations, which also links to [this MSO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) on accepting an answer which explains it's pretty much to give other users chance to post an answer - if you see a question with the green tick of acceptance it's less likely that they'll post another answer.

Comment: And what's the tragedy if they don't post another answer considering that the solution has been found?

Comment: @OC2PS - they can still answer their own question, and are encouraged to do so. They just can't give it the checkmark. So if they forget to come back and checkmark it, the answer is still there and should float to the top.